How to use variable value declared in Microsoft PowerPoint Object module in Main Module
I need to refer the variables in slide object modules to refresh the charts which I am struggling since a week.
Could anyone help me please?
I just need make Slide2146449163 as variable since SRngMkt, SRngClt etc are defined in Slide2146449163. I have similar slides for other markets and countries
Public Sub test()

Set ActSld = ActiveWindow.View.Slide
Debug.Print ActSld.Name
SldNum = ActSld.SlideID
'SldNum = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
Debug.Print SldNum

Debug.Print ActSld.Name, ActSld.SlideID, ActSld.SlideNumber, ActSld.SlideIndex

Debug.Print ActSld.SRngMkt <--- ActSld should be dynamic. Giving error
Debug.Print Slide2146449163.SRngClt <--- works perfectly fine
Debug.Print Slide2146449163.SRngHub
Debug.Print Slide2146449163.SRngCTSS

End Sub


Below is the code written in slide object module
Public Sub cmd_Ink_CEE_Germany_Click()

SRngMkt = "CENTRAL & EASTERN EUROPE"
SRngClt = "*"
SRngHub = "Germany"
SRngCTSS = "Included"

Call test

End Sub

enter image description here


Pass 4 arguments to Refresh_Charts
btw, Dim SRngCTSS, SRngClt As String declares SRngCTSS as a Variant variable. There are several instances in your snippet.

Public Sub Refresh_Charts(SRngCTSS As String, SRngClt As String,  SRngHub As String,  SRngCTSS As String)
'...'
xlWS.Range("E4").Value = SRngMkt <------- This line is working but Slide2146449163 should be dynamic
xlWS.Range("J4").Value = SRngClt
xlWS.Range("O4").Value = SRngHub
xlWS.Range("T4").Value = SRngCTSS
'...'
End Sub


Public Sub cmd_Ink_CEE_Germany_Click()
    ' Use local variables
    Dim SRngCTSS As String, SRngClt As String, SRngHub As String, SRngCTSS As String
    SRngMkt = "CENTRAL & EASTERN EUROPE"
    SRngClt = "*"
    SRngHub = "Germany"
    SRngCTSS = "Included"
    ' pass arguments to Refresh_Charts
    Call Refresh_Charts(SRngCTSS, SRngClt,  SRngHub,  SRngCTSS)

End Sub

